# How can I update a table FK column with unique value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Departments` and `Workers`.

`Departments` table has a `ManagerID` column. I choose managerID from `Workers.ID` and add to `Departments.ManagerID` but no one can be manager of different departments at the same time. How can I control it in an update query?

Departments table

[image]

Workers table

[image]

Comment: You want to add `Workers.ID` in `Departments.ManagerID` only if the id are different ?

Comment: yes every manager ıd must be unique

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?  Perhaps showing three or four records in your table before and after the update?

Comment: If this is a rule that a manager may only manage one department than I would check this in a trigger and block the update/insert there

Comment: or even easier create an unique constraint on Departments.ManagerID

Comment: ı added photos of tables in description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to block managers from being manager for more than one department than the easiest way is to create an unique index on the Departments table on the column ManagerID

```
create unique nonclustered index UX_ManagerID on Departments (ManagerID)
where ManagerID is NOT NULL;
```

Now all updates and inserts that attempt to make a manager the boss of more than one department will fail.
In the error message the name 'UX_ManagerID' will be present so you can check that in the exception message and give a nice message to the user.